# Clickstream sample dataset

Tags: data-request, business, internet

I am looking for some web traffic or clickstream dataset, ideally from an ecommerce website. I like to do some analysis on purchasing pattern if possible.

For example: visit duration, conversion, shopping cart abandonment, cross-category shopping, promotion behavior...

I can setup a place to upload the file.

Comment: https://my.vertica.com/docs/4.1/HTML/Master/4314.htm

Comment: I googled that too but then where to download? lol It seems just a help page / doc

Comment: https://my.vertica.com/docs/4.1/HTML/Master/4374.htm

Comment: @philshem nothing found on those two links

Answer (score 10):

**Dataset 1:**

[Wikipedia Releases Clickstream Data](https://www.datainnovation.org/2015/02/wikipedia-releases-clickstream-data/)

Wikipedia has released a data set of clickstream data for January 2015. A clickstream is the path a user requests to get to a desired web page or article by using a referer—clicking on a link or performing a search. The dataset contains 22 million referer-article pairs from the English language, desktop version of Wikipedia—just a sample of the 4 billion total requests made in January. Clickstream data is a valuable analytical tool as it can determine things like the most popular links in a web page and how users navigate through a website.

Download data from: https://figshare.com/articles/Wikipedia_Clickstream/1305770

**Dataset 2:**

[Visualize Website Clickstream Data](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/visualize-website-clickstream-data/)

These website log files contain data elements such as a date and time stamp, the visitor’s IP address, the destination URLs of the pages visited, and a user ID that uniquely identifies the website visitor.

Download data from : https://s3.amazonaws.com/hw-sandbox/tutorial8/RefineDemoData.zip

**Dataset 3:**

[Sample Clickstream Data](https://gist.github.com/matthayes/4614332)

Download data from : https://gist.github.com/matthayes/4614332

Answer (score 4):

This may be for only an old version (4.1), but...

<s>[ClickStream Example Database](https://my.vertica.com/docs/4.1/HTML/Master/4314.htm)</s> [Wayback Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150319234902/https://my.vertica.com/docs/4.1/HTML/Master/4314.htm)

> **Example Database File Locations**
>
> The example databases are installed in:
>
> /opt/vertica/examples/ClickStream_Schema

Update: <s>[Download instructions](https://community.dev.hpe.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/Where-is-the-ClickStream-Example/td-p/215141)</s> (link denied due to registration)