# labeled clickstream datasets for intrusion detection

Tags: data-request, security

I am looking for some clickstream datasets, ideally from an ecommerce website, where the click paths are assigned labels (e.g. good to say that a click path is originating from a genuine user, and bad if the click path is originating from an intruder). I would like to study the behavior of system intruders. I know there are some clickstream datasets out there but those aren't labeled

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clickstream sample dataset](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/clickstream-sample-dataset)

Comment: It is not in the sense that those datasets aren't labeled.